# How to check a CheckBox programmatically using Android C#?

Tags: c#, android, checkbox, xamarin

How to check a CheckBox programmatically using Android C#? I can't find any solution for this, there are only Java examples of this.

I tried to use SetChecked but that function doesn't exists.

```
void btnChangeCB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
if (cb1.Checked == true) {
    cb1.Toggle ();
  }
```

Anyway I can toggle the checkboxes, but I can't check them :(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply assign `true` to the `Checked` property:

```
cb1.Checked = true; // Check the checkbox.
```

In Java properties don't exist. They use Get/Set method pairs. Xamarin condensed them into a property:

In Java:

```
public bool GetChecked();
public void SetChecked(bool value);
```

In C#:

```
public bool Checked { get; set; }
```

Comment: Oh god. I make myself too hard. I tried this but I used "==" that's why it doesn't worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @lukso: `==` is comparison, `=` is assignment.

Answer (score 2):

**For checking the CheckBox**

```
checkBox1.Checked = true;
```

**For Unchecking the CheckBox**

```
checkBox1.Checked = false;
```